# Symfony HTTP Cache invalidation

Tags: symfony, http, caching, cache-control, http-caching

Here's the deal. Symfony 2.8 setup. I want to serve cached rendered content with Symfony HTTP Cache (content rarely changes) **and** to be able to invalidate it whenever I want.

When I use Symfony HTTP cache like this:

```
$response = new JsonResponse($data, Response::HTTP_OK);
$response->setPublic();
$response->setSharedMaxAge(3600);
$response->headers->addCacheControlDirective('must-revalidate', true);
$response->setVary('Accept-Encoding');
```

It results in following headers:

```
Cache-Control:must-revalidate, public, s-maxage=3600
vary:Accept-Encoding
```

Content gets cached, but because of cache control set to `public`, intermediate proxies can cache it as well and obviously I can't invalidate data there.
On the other hand setting cache control to `private` will force Symfony HTTP cache to not store it.

With Varnish (which I can't use in this case) I would send `Cache-Control: public` from the app server and overwrite it to `Cache-Control: private` with VCL rule, so browsers always return to check for a fresh version.

I wonder if I should do something similar with Symfony HTTP Cache (override Cache-Control header once response passes caching layer) or is there a simpler way?